# Is there a way to take a screenshot of a "layer" preserving its transparency, in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Say, for example, I have a `<body>` with a photo of my failed marriage, and on top of that I have a semitransparent `<div>` with `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)`:

[image: example html]

I want to make a screenshot of that `<div>` as a 32 bit PNG, with no photo of my failed marriage showing through, only the half opaque black of the `<div>` itself:

[image: example element screenshot]

I am not entirely sure but Firefox can do that, except it doesn't preserve the transparency:

[image: firefox screenshot]

Instead, Safari can do exactly what I want, if I recall correctly.

Is there some extension I could use?